# Is it possible to have multiple .testcaferc.json files in TestCafe 1.x per environment?

Tags: testing, configuration, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

**Summary**
Is it possible to have multiple .testcaferc.json files in TestCafe 1.x per environment? For example:

```
 - .testcaferc.json                // contains base configuration 
 - .testcaferc.dev.json            // contains development overrides
 - .testcaferc.prod.json           // contains production overrides
```

`testcafe --env=development`

**Note:** I'm specifically asking about the `.testcaferc.json`, not a custom `config.json` as that would require `import`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now, only one .testcaferc.json file is supported. Support for multiple configuration files was [requested on GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3522) and looks like they may implement it [as part of another feature](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3428), but no timeline was given.